# How to capture all the events & actions (including ribbon actions) performed on a word document through macro code

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

In my dotm macro template, I have a content control which contains some text. This text should not be visible to the user so I made it transparent by setting the text's transparency property to 1.0 Now this works fine even if you change the background color of the page and create documents out of it etc.

The real problem is when we press ctrl + A (which selects all the text) and change the font color. At that point the text suddenly appears and this is very likely to happen from the user's end.

So I thought instead of focusing just on this particular case I would rather set transparency 1.0 on all the events that are possible by a user to be performed on a word document (to get a concrete solution).

So is there an event in macro which could catch all the events and actions?